# Wordpress header modifications acting up

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to modify the twentyfifteen theme to have the basic lay-out like in the picture here: [image]
With the top bar with the logo and image at the top and the menu on the side below the top bar. My attempt was to add a div straight at the opening of the body tag in the header to see if the placement would work. It is visible but it doesn't "push down" the side menu like I want it to be (like in the picture.

This is my header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div style="background-color: black; width: 100%; height: 100px;"></div>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentyfifteen' ); ?></a>

    <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
        <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
            <div class="site-branding">
                <?php
                    twentyfifteen_the_custom_logo();

                    if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) : ?>
                        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <p class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
                    <?php endif;

                    $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
                    if ( $description || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
                        <p class="site-description"><?php echo $description; ?></p>
                    <?php endif;
                ?>
                <button class="secondary-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu and widgets', 'twentyfifteen' ); ?></button>
            </div><!-- .site-branding -->
        </header><!-- .site-header -->

        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div><!-- .sidebar -->

    <div id="content" class="site-content">
```

In case it is relevant I also attached the theme's stylesheet [here](https://pastebin.com/4rXuXf51).

With my modifications this is how the div shows up:
[image]

The black bar should be above the menu on the left and push it down.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you insert it into the sidebar div and not outside of it, create another div before "sidebar"

Comment: I did create the div before the sidebar element. I also can't find the conflicting css (position absolute, align left) that could be the issue.